# Build C++ in Powershell not CMD with Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, powershell, sublimetext3

I'm wondering if there is a way to run builds in Sublime Text 3 so that it outputs in Powershell and not CMD.

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code I found online that will use MinGW as the compiler and allow you to press Ctrl + B to build a C++ program in ST3. When you do this the output goes to the CMD prompt. Is there a way to make the output go to Powershell instead?

Comment: Change `cmd` and `/k` to PowerShell equivalents (`powershell` and `-NoExit -Command` will probably work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for sure.

```
    {
    "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["start", "powershell", "-NoExit", "${file_path}//${file_base_name}.exe"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, this is giving me a bunch of errors for me, IDK why.
Maybe I need to change gcc to g++ ???

UPDATE : 
It did work after changing gcc to g++, but I don't see the terminal window pop up, it simply prints  `[Finished in 1.7s]`  in the console @Ankur Bhardwaj